# Internet connection via WIFI stops/slows down significantly after turning on bluetooth

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, internet, connection

After turning on Bluetooth and connecting headphones, laptop stays connected to WIFI but internet connection goes down.

Here's output for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`:

```
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0901]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

And for `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e500 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 174f:2426 Syntek Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: It's not ubuntu issue.

Comment: If your wireless network is using the 2.4GHz band, then this would be expected given the interference from the Bluetooth radio, which also operates at 2.4GHz. As your card is 802.11ac capable, it would be a good idea to check to ensure you're using the 5GHz band if at all possible.

Comment: It might not be an Ubuntu issue but it's definitely a Linux one. This problem doesn't occur on windows(on the same laptop).